# How to enable scroll on background component even if a Modal is Open?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, class, angular-material

I have a problem with Angular and Material for Angular, I have an application with many modals, they all lock background scrolling when they're open, but I have a notification modal, this notification modal isn't intended to block background scrolling.

I don't have any .noScroll class in this modal, but the background page in relation to the modal still won't scroll, I want to the user to be able to scroll the page even with the notification modal open.

The notification modal is a DialogRef from Material for Angular.

I tried using overflow: visible and auto, also tried to modify the backdrop to enable scroll, but no success :(

How do I make the backdrop of this particular modal to enable scrolling and possible override other configurations of the code?

Edit: Here is part of the code >

ModalService:

```
{
    constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) {
        }   

 openNotificationsModal(topOffset, rightOffset): MatDialogRef<NotificationsModalComponent> {
        return this.notificationsModal(topOffset, rightOffset);
    }

    private notificationsModal(topOffset, rightOffset, clazz?: string): MatDialogRef<NotificationsModalComponent> {
            const config = {
                panelClass: clazz ? clazz : 'notifications-modal',
                backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
                data: {
                    topOffset,
                    rightOffset,
                }
            };
            return this.matDialog.open(NotificationsModalComponent, config);
        }
    }
```

this is my modal component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'aa-notifications-modal',
    templateUrl: './notifications-modal.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class NotificationsModalComponent {

    constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NotificationsModalComponent>) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.dialogRef.updatePosition({
            top: '2.5rem'
        });
    }

    output() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

this is the scss of this modal:

```
    aa-notifications-modal {
    width: 100%;
}
.notifications-modal {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
    .mat-dialog-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background: transparent;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .align-triangle {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding: 0;
        .triangle {
            margin-right: 4rem;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 25px solid transparent;
            border-right: 25px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 25px solid #fff;
        }
    }

    .space {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .content-modal {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin-right: 8rem;
        aa-notifications-list {
            width: 427px;
            pointer-events: auto;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Little curious about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you need to find out where `overflow: hidden;` likely it will be on body tag, a simple solution you can try to set `overflow: auto !important;`
But more elegant  will be to provide [Scroll strategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) into your Dialog

Comment: I tried changing overflows to auto !important, no luck, I'll look at the scroll strategy